# php printing a message in a div

Tags: php

Can I have someone watch this for me? I want to echo $msg in this div.

```
$msg = "five";
$msg1 = "<div class='warning'><img src='images/warning_icon.png' alt='Information' width='32' height='29' class='icon' /><strong>Warning:</strong>you've added <?php echo $msg; ?> number of products<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);'><img src='images/close_icon.gif' width='6' height='6' alt='Close' /></a></div>";
```

Comment: Ask for a third hand too. To accept answers for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? You're not just asking for `<div><?php echo $msg; ?></div>` are you?

Comment: In which div? It seems that a part of your code is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be okay.

```
$msg1 = "<div class='warning'>
<img src='images/warning_icon.png' alt='Information' width='32' height='29' class='icon' />
<strong>Warning:</strong>you've added " . $msg . " number of products<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);'>
<img src='images/close_icon.gif' width='6' height='6' alt='Close' /></a>
</div>";
```

The problem was you mixed php with php when you placed `<?php...` inside of the string `$msg1`.

Comment: @karto then please click the arrow next to my answer :)

Comment: @karto don't you see the pipe next to my answer?

Comment: @fabrik: i've accepted it as an answer. havent u seen it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood, but it looks like you might just need

```
echo "<div>$msg</div>";
```

You might also want to take a look at this introductory page on strings: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_string.asp

Comment: @ the -1 person: please go trough OP's history and check out the question as it was by the time  answered. Didn't that "not sure I understood" ring a bell?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to echo a php command in php (in msg1 you have  in the string. As you are using double quotes you can include php variables in the string).

Change your code to:

```
$msg1 = "<div class='warning'><img src='images/warning_icon.png' alt='Information' width='32' height='29' class='icon' /><strong>Warning:</strong>you've added $msg number of products<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);'><img src='images/close_icon.gif' width='6' height='6' alt='Close' /></a></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$msg = "five";
$msg1 = "<div class='warning'><img src='images/warning_icon.png' alt='Information' width='32' height='29' class='icon' /><strong>Warning:</strong>you've added ".$msg." number of products<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);'><img src='images/close_icon.gif' width='6' height='6' alt='Close' /></a></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$msg = "five";
$msg1 = "<div class='warning'><img src='images/warning_icon.png' alt='Information' width='32' height='29' class='icon' /><strong>Warning:</strong>you've added". $msg ."number of products<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);'><img src='images/close_icon.gif' width='6' height='6' alt='Close' /></a></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `<?php echo $msg; ?>` inside a php script. you only need to use `<?php` once to tell the parser that it's a php script.

```
$msg = "five";
$msg1 = "<div class='warning'><img src='images/warning_icon.png' alt='Information' width='32' height='29' class='icon' /><strong>Warning:</strong>you've added $msg number of products<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);'><img src='images/close_icon.gif' width='6' height='6' alt='Close' /></a></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this `{$msg}`

```
$msg = "five";
echo $msg1 = "<div class='warning'><img src='images/warning_icon.png' alt='Information' width='32' height='29' class='icon' /><strong>Warning:</strong>you've added {$msg} number of products<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);'><img src='images/close_icon.gif' width='6' height='6' alt='Close' /></a></div>";
```